# Erro ao converter json com listas de objetos para um objeto dart

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Bom dia a todos!
Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao tentar converter um json para dart.
**[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String'**

Meu código

```html
import 'horarios_modelo.dart';
import 'pontos_modelo.dart';

class UsuarioModelo {
  final String nome;
  final String pis;
  final String cargo;
  final bool admin;
  final String cnpj;
  final String centroCusto;
  final List<PontoModelo> pontos;
  final List<HorarioModelo> horarios;

  UsuarioModelo({
    this.nome,
    this.pis,
    this.cargo,
    this.admin,
    this.cnpj,
    this.centroCusto,
    this.pontos,
    this.horarios,
  });

  factory UsuarioModelo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    var listP = parsedJson['pontos'] as List;
    print(listP.runtimeType);
    List<PontoModelo> pontosList = listP.map((i) => PontoModelo.fromJson(i)).toList();

    var listH = parsedJson['horarios'] as List;
    print(listH.runtimeType);
    List<HorarioModelo> horariossList = listH.map((j) => HorarioModelo.fromJson(j)).toList();

    return UsuarioModelo(
        nome: parsedJson['name'],
        pis: parsedJson['pis'],
        cargo: parsedJson['cargo'],
        admin: parsedJson['admin'],
        cnpj: parsedJson['cnpj'],
        centroCusto: parsedJson['centroCusto'],
        pontos: pontosList,
        horarios: horariossList
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'nome': nome,
    'pis': pis,
    'cargo': cargo,
    'admin': admin,
    'cnpj': cnpj,
    'centroCusto': centroCusto,
    'pontos': new List<dynamic>.from(pontos.map((x) => x.runtimeType)),
    'horarios': new List<dynamic>.from(horarios.map((x) => x.runtimeType)),
  };
}


class HorarioModelo {
  final String diaDaSemana;
  final String entrada1;
  final String saida1;
  final String entrada2;
  final String saida2;
  final String entrada3;
  final String saida3;
  final bool flexivel;
  final bool ehFolga;

  HorarioModelo({
    this.diaDaSemana,
    this.entrada1,
    this.saida1,
    this.entrada2,
    this.saida2,
    this.entrada3,
    this.saida3,
    this.flexivel,
    this.ehFolga,
  });

  factory HorarioModelo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return HorarioModelo(
        diaDaSemana: parsedJson['diaDaSemana'],
        entrada1: parsedJson['entrada1'],
        saida1: parsedJson['saida1'],
        entrada2: parsedJson['entrada2'],
        saida2: parsedJson['saida2'],
        entrada3: parsedJson['entrada3'],
        saida3: parsedJson['saida3'],
        flexivel: parsedJson['flexivel'],
        ehFolga: parsedJson['ehFolga']
    );
  }
}

class PontoModelo {
  final String dia;
  final String entrada1;
  final String saida1;
  final String entrada2;
  final String saida2;
  final String entrada3;
  final String saida3;

  PontoModelo({
    this.dia,
    this.entrada1,
    this.saida1,
    this.entrada2,
    this.saida2,
    this.entrada3,
    this.saida3,
  });

  factory PontoModelo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return PontoModelo(
        dia: parsedJson['dia'],
        entrada1: parsedJson['entrada1'],
        saida1: parsedJson['saida1'],
        entrada2: parsedJson["entrada2"],
        saida2: parsedJson['saida2'],
        entrada3: parsedJson['entrada3'],
        saida3: parsedJson['saida3']
    );
  }
}

Método para pegar o dados
Future<dynamic> getDado(JsonUser user) async {
    var url = "http://200.201.144.179:8080/ikponto";
    var uri = '/servico/sessao/funcionario/obter-dados-gerais';
    var token = user.token;
    //envia enviado no Header com a chave
    //Authorization e valor Bearer {token} .
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    dio.options.headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
      'idFuncionario': user.id
    };
    dio.options.contentType = ContentType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    Response  response =  await dio. post (url+uri, data : {
      "idFuncionario":user.id
    });
    var body = response;
    print(body);
    var responseJson = json.decode(response.data);
    return responseJson;
  }
  
  Meu login, ele passa perfeitamene mas na hora de converter para o usuario ele me retorna esse erro.
  child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Text("Login"),
                              color: Colors.red,
                              onPressed:
                              () async {
                                var respLogin = await _loginServico.login(_emailController.text, _senhaController.text);
                                JsonUser user = JsonUser.fromJson(respLogin);
                                var respDados =  await _loginServico.getDado(user);
                                usuario = UsuarioModelo.fromJson(respDados);
                                print(usuario.nome);
                                if (usuario != null) {
                                 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return new HomePage(
                                          usuario: usuario,
                                        );
                                      }));
                                } else {
                                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(content: Text("E-mail ou Senha não confere")));
                                }
                              },
                            ),
```

Comment: Ficaria mais fácil se adicionasse o `json` que está sendo retornado, também destacar a linha/comando exato onde o erro ocorre.

Comment: Ok.                          var respDados =  await _loginServico.getDado(user);
                                usuario = UsuarioModelo.fromJson(respDados);

Answer (score -1):

```html
Resposta JSON :
{
"nome": "Adilson Junior",
"pis":"1234567890",
"cargo": "PROGRAMADOR JR III",
"admin": false,
"cnpj": "12004232000105",
"centroCusto": "DESENVOLVIMENTO",
"pontos": [
{
"dia": "01/01/2019",
"entrada1": null,
"saida1": null,
"entrada2": null,
"saida2": null,
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null
},
{
"dia": "02/01/2019",
"entrada1": "02/01/2019 07:58",
"saida1": "02/01/2019 12:07",
"entrada2": "02/01/2019 13:07",
"saida2": "02/01/2019 18:03",
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null
},
{
"dia": "03/01/2019",
"entrada1": "03/01/2019 07:57",
"saida1": "03/01/2019 12:21",
"entrada2": "03/01/2019 13:23",
"saida2": "03/01/2019 18:00",
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null
}
],
"horarios": [
{
"diaDaSemana": "Seg",
"entrada1": "08:00",
"saida1": "12:00",
"entrada2": "13:00",
"saida2": "18:00",
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null,
"flexivel": false,
"ehFolga": false
},
{
"diaDaSemana": "Ter",
"entrada1": "08:00",
"saida1": "12:00",
"entrada2": "13:00",
"saida2": "18:00",
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null,
"flexivel": false,
"ehFolga": false
},
{
"diaDaSemana": "Qua",
"entrada1": "08:00",
"saida1": "12:00",
"entrada2": "13:00",
"saida2": "18:00",
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null,
"flexivel": false,
"ehFolga": false
},
{
"diaDaSemana": "Qui",
"entrada1": "08:00",
"saida1": "12:00",
"entrada2": "13:00",
"saida2": "18:00",
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null,
"flexivel": false,
"ehFolga": false
},
{
"diaDaSemana": "Sex",
"entrada1": "08:00",
"saida1": "12:00",
"entrada2": "13:00",
"saida2": "17:00",
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null,
"flexivel": false,
"ehFolga": false
},
{
"diaDaSemana": "SÃ¡b",
"entrada1": null,
"saida1": null,
"entrada2": null,
"saida2": null,
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null,
"flexivel": false,
"ehFolga": true
},
{
"diaDaSemana": "Dom",
"entrada1": null,
"saida1": null,
"entrada2": null,
"saida2": null,
"entrada3": null,
"saida3": null,
"flexivel": false,
"ehFolga": true
}
]
}
```

Comment: Edite sua resposta e adicione o arquivo JSON nela, esse espaço aqui é somente para respostas. Você pode editar por [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/407366/edit)